# List selection model not working on android mobile device

Tags: gluon, gluon-mobile

I have code which looks like:

```
lst.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(
(ob, ov, nv) -> { .... do something})
```

The lst is a ListView. It runs fine when testing on desktop but the selection listener does not seem to work when deployed to an Android mobile device. The objective is to select and item from the list which then brings up a item detail view. Should I be taking a different approach?

Any help appreciated.

Thanks

EDIT:
As suggested I looked at the logcat output.

The initial call to the REST service to get data and test that logging is working:

```
10-27 12:38:35.699 25889-25940/edu.uconn.chatter I/System.out: **************************** Test to see if log is working.
10-27 12:38:35.709 25889-26656/edu.uconn.chatter I/RestDataSource: Created Rest Connection:
                                                                    Method: GET
                                                                    Request URL: http://192.168.10.77:8080/search/test
                                                                    Form Params: {}
                                                                    ContentType: null
                                                                    Consumer Credentials: null / null
10-27 12:38:35.709 25889-26656/edu.uconn.chatter I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
10-27 12:38:35.709 25889-26656/edu.uconn.chatter I/System.out: (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
```

This does return data which appears in the list. The following output is from trying to touch a row in the list. There are debug statements in the appropriate methods but they are not printed out. I assume that's because they are not being invoked:

```
10-27 12:41:21.169 25889-25889/edu.uconn.chatter D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
10-27 12:41:21.169 25889-25889/edu.uconn.chatter E/FXEntity: call native MultitouchEvent, density = 4.0, touchXs0 = 401
10-27 12:41:21.169 25889-25940/edu.uconn.chatter I/GLASS: Call InternalSurfaceView_onMultiTouchEventNative
10-27 12:41:21.169 25889-25940/edu.uconn.chatter I/GLASS: Glass will pass multitouchevent to monocle with count = 1
10-27 12:41:21.179 25889-25889/edu.uconn.chatter E/FXEntity: call native MultitouchEvent, density = 4.0, touchXs0 = 401
10-27 12:41:21.179 25889-25940/edu.uconn.chatter I/GLASS: Call InternalSurfaceView_onMultiTouchEventNative
10-27 12:41:21.179 25889-25940/edu.uconn.chatter I/GLASS: Glass will pass multitouchevent to monocle with count = 1
10-27 12:41:21.209 25889-25889/edu.uconn.chatter E/FXEntity: call native MultitouchEvent, density = 4.0, touchXs0 = 401
10-27 12:41:21.229 25889-25940/edu.uconn.chatter I/GLASS: Call InternalSurfaceView_onMultiTouchEventNative
10-27 12:41:21.229 25889-25940/edu.uconn.chatter I/GLASS: Glass will pass multitouchevent to monocle with count = 1
10-27 12:41:21.229 25889-25889/edu.uconn.chatter E/FXEntity: call native MultitouchEvent, density = 4.0, touchXs0 = 401
10-27 12:41:21.229 25889-25940/edu.uconn.chatter I/GLASS: Call InternalSurfaceView_onMultiTouchEventNative
10-27 12:41:21.229 25889-25940/edu.uconn.chatter I/GLASS: Glass will pass multitouchevent to monocle with count = 1
10-27 12:41:21.249 25889-25889/edu.uconn.chatter E/FXEntity: call native MultitouchEvent, density = 4.0, touchXs0 = 401
10-27 12:41:21.249 25889-25940/edu.uconn.chatter I/GLASS: Call InternalSurfaceView_onMultiTouchEventNative
10-27 12:41:21.249 25889-25940/edu.uconn.chatter I/GLASS: Glass will pass multitouchevent to monocle with count = 1
10-27 12:41:21.259 25889-25889/edu.uconn.chatter E/FXEntity: call native MultitouchEvent, density = 4.0, touchXs0 = 401
10-27 12:41:21.259 25889-25940/edu.uconn.chatter I/GLASS: Call InternalSurfaceView_onMultiTouchEventNative
10-27 12:41:21.259 25889-25940/edu.uconn.chatter I/GLASS: Glass will pass multitouchevent to monocle with count = 1
10-27 12:41:21.279 25889-25889/edu.uconn.chatter E/FXEntity: call native MultitouchEvent, density = 4.0, touchXs0 = 401
10-27 12:41:21.279 25889-25940/edu.uconn.chatter I/GLASS: Call InternalSurfaceView_onMultiTouchEventNative
10-27 12:41:21.279 25889-25940/edu.uconn.chatter I/GLASS: Glass will pass multitouchevent to monocle with count = 1
10-27 12:41:21.279 25889-25889/edu.uconn.chatter D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 1
10-27 12:41:21.279 25889-25889/edu.uconn.chatter E/FXEntity: call native MultitouchEvent, density = 4.0, touchXs0 = 401
10-27 12:41:21.279 25889-25940/edu.uconn.chatter I/GLASS: Call InternalSurfaceView_onMultiTouchEventNative
10-27 12:41:21.279 25889-25940/edu.uconn.chatter I/GLASS: Glass will pass multitouchevent to monocle with count = 1
10-27 12:41:21.279 25889-25940/edu.uconn.chatter I/System.out: don't add points, primary = -1
```

Thanks

EDIT 2:

I agree it should work the same. Probably something I'm doing that's causing the issue. If you have a working sample could you post that? As far as the device its a Samsung Edge 6, Android version 6.0.1. Here's the code to the class:

```
package edu.uconn.chatter.views;

import com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.animation.BounceInRightTransition;
import com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.application.MobileApplication;
import com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.control.AppBar;
import com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.mvc.View;
import com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.visual.MaterialDesignIcon;
import com.gluonhq.connect.ConnectState;
import com.gluonhq.connect.GluonObservableList;
import edu.uconn.chatter.App;
import edu.uconn.chatter.model.BeneNameBO;
import edu.uconn.chatter.model.CurrentBene;
import edu.uconn.chatter.services.BeneLookupService;
import edu.uconn.chatter.views.dlgs.ErrorDlg;
import javafx.application.Platform;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.*;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class LookupPresenter implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private View lookup;

    @FXML
    private TextField searchParam;

    @FXML
    private ListView<BeneNameBO> beneList;

    @FXML
    private Button search;

    @Inject
    private CurrentBene currentBene;

    @Inject
    private BeneLookupService beneLookupService;

    @Inject
    private ErrorDlg errorDlgView;

    public LookupPresenter() {
        super();
    }

    // After constructor
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        // Screen Transition
        lookup.setShowTransitionFactory(BounceInRightTransition::new);

        // Set cell factory for benelist
        beneList.setCellFactory(lv -> new ListCell<BeneNameBO>() {
            @Override
            public void updateItem(BeneNameBO item, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(item, empty);
                if (!empty) {
                    setText(item.getLastName() + ", " + item.getFirstName());
                } else {
                    setText(null);
                }
            }
        });
        beneList.setPlaceholder(new Label("Make a selection"));

        // Need a query parameter
        search.disableProperty().bind(Bindings.createBooleanBinding(() -> {
            return searchParam.textProperty().isEmpty().get();
        }, searchParam.textProperty()));

        // Set up view
        lookup.showingProperty().addListener((obs, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            if (newValue) {
                AppBar appBar = MobileApplication.getInstance().getAppBar();

                // Return to bene form view
                appBar.setNavIcon(MaterialDesignIcon.ARROW_BACK.button(e ->
                        MobileApplication.getInstance().switchView(App.BENEFORM_VIEW)));
                appBar.setTitleText("Look up");

                // Allow to logout from this view
                appBar.getActionItems().add(MaterialDesignIcon.POWER.button(e ->
                        MobileApplication.getInstance().switchView(App.PRIMARY_VIEW)));
            }
        });
    }

    @FXML
    private void onSearch(ActionEvent click) {
        System.out.println("**************************** Test to see if log is working.");

        GluonObservableList<BeneNameBO> benes =
                beneLookupService.findBenes(searchParam.getText());

        // Error handler
        benes.exceptionProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            //showErrorDlg(newValue.getMessage());
            errorDlgView.showError(newValue.getMessage());
        });

        // Populate list
        benes.stateProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            if (newValue == ConnectState.SUCCEEDED) {
                if (benes != null && benes.size() > 0) {
                    beneList.setItems(benes);

                    Platform.runLater(() -> {
                        beneList.getSelectionModel().selectedItemProperty().addListener(
                                (obs, ov, nv) -> {
                                    System.out.println("****************************** In list click event handler:");
                                    if (nv != null) {
                                        setCurrentBeneId((BeneNameBO) nv);
                                    } else {
                                        setCurrentBeneId((BeneNameBO) ov);
                                    }

                                    MobileApplication.getInstance().switchView(App.BENEFORM_VIEW);
                                });
                    });
                } else {
                    final Label label = new Label("Nothing found, try again.");
                    beneList.setPlaceholder(label);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void setCurrentBeneId(BeneNameBO beneNameBO) {
        System.out.println("******************************Process call for ID:" + beneNameBO.getBeneId());
        currentBene.clearCurrent();
        currentBene.activeBene().get().setBeneId(beneNameBO.getBeneId());
    }
}
```

Again, thanks for the help.

Edit 3: 
This approaches works. Here's the code in case anyone else is having a similar issue.

```
package edu.uconn.chatter.widgets;

import com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.control.ListTile;
import com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.visual.MaterialDesignIcon;
import edu.uconn.chatter.model.BeneNameBO;
import javafx.scene.control.ListCell;

import java.util.function.Consumer;

/**
 * Created by johndestefano on 10/27/16.
 */
public class BeneListCell extends ListCell<BeneNameBO> {
    private ListTile tile;
    private BeneNameBO beneNameBO;

    public BeneListCell(Consumer<BeneNameBO> processEvt) {
        tile = new ListTile();
        tile.setOnMouseClicked(e -> {
            System.out.println("********************* Item clicked" + tile.textProperty().size());
            processEvt.accept(beneNameBO);
        });
        setText(null);
    }

    @Override
    protected void updateItem(BeneNameBO item, boolean empty) {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        this.beneNameBO = item;

        if (item != null && !empty) {
            tile.textProperty().setAll(item.getLastName());
            tile.setPrimaryGraphic(MaterialDesignIcon.DESCRIPTION.graphic());
            tile.setSecondaryGraphic(MaterialDesignIcon.STAR.graphic("-fx-fill: green"));
            setGraphic(tile);
        } else {
            setGraphic(null);
        }
    }
}
```

And the Presenter:

```
package edu.uconn.chatter.views;

import com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.animation.BounceInRightTransition;
import com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.application.MobileApplication;
import com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.control.AppBar;
import com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.mvc.View;
import com.gluonhq.charm.glisten.visual.MaterialDesignIcon;
import com.gluonhq.connect.ConnectState;
import com.gluonhq.connect.GluonObservableList;
import edu.uconn.chatter.App;
import edu.uconn.chatter.model.BeneNameBO;
import edu.uconn.chatter.model.CurrentBene;
import edu.uconn.chatter.services.BeneLookupService;
import edu.uconn.chatter.views.dlgs.ErrorDlg;
import edu.uconn.chatter.widgets.BeneListCell;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.fxml.Initializable;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ResourceBundle;

public class LookupPresenter implements Initializable {

    @FXML
    private View lookup;

    @FXML
    private TextField searchParam;

    @FXML
    private ListView<BeneNameBO> beneList;

    @FXML
    private Button search;

    @Inject
    private CurrentBene currentBene;

    @Inject
    private BeneLookupService beneLookupService;

    @Inject
    private ErrorDlg errorDlgView;

    public LookupPresenter() {
        super();
    }

    // After constructor
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        // Screen Transition
        lookup.setShowTransitionFactory(BounceInRightTransition::new);

        // Set cell factory for benelist
        beneList.setCellFactory(lv -> new BeneListCell(bn -> {
            System.out.println("******************************Process call for ID:" + bn.getBeneId());
            currentBene.clearCurrent();
            currentBene.activeBene().get().setBeneId(bn.getBeneId());
            MobileApplication.getInstance().switchView(App.BENEFORM_VIEW);
        }));
        beneList.setPlaceholder(new Label("Make a selection"));

        // Need a query parameter
        search.disableProperty().bind(Bindings.createBooleanBinding(() -> {
            return searchParam.textProperty().isEmpty().get();
        }, searchParam.textProperty()));

        // Set up view
        lookup.showingProperty().addListener((obs, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            if (newValue) {
                AppBar appBar = MobileApplication.getInstance().getAppBar();

                // Return to bene form view
                appBar.setNavIcon(MaterialDesignIcon.ARROW_BACK.button(e ->
                        MobileApplication.getInstance().switchView(App.BENEFORM_VIEW)));
                appBar.setTitleText("Look up");

                // Allow to logout from this view
                appBar.getActionItems().add(MaterialDesignIcon.POWER.button(e ->
                        MobileApplication.getInstance().switchView(App.PRIMARY_VIEW)));
            }
        });
    }

    @FXML
    private void onSearch(ActionEvent click) {
        System.out.println("**************************** Test to see if log is working.");

        GluonObservableList<BeneNameBO> benes =
                beneLookupService.findBenes(searchParam.getText());

        // Error handler
        benes.exceptionProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            //showErrorDlg(newValue.getMessage());
            errorDlgView.showError(newValue.getMessage());
        });

        // Populate list
        benes.stateProperty().addListener((observable, oldValue, newValue) -> {
            if (newValue == ConnectState.SUCCEEDED) {
                if (benes != null && benes.size() > 0) {
                    beneList.setItems(benes);
                } else {
                    final Label label = new Label("Nothing found, try again.");
                    beneList.setPlaceholder(label);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: If you are using a regular JavaFX `ListView`, there is no different between desktop or Android implementation, so the listener should work. Try to debug it (adding some system.out printouts and make sure there are no exceptions or other issues. Then run `adb logcat -v threadtime` on the console to track those printouts.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I did add some system.out logging and on the desktop I can see the log statement. When looking at the logcat output I don't see the statements: Here what I do see (full verbose logging):10-27 12:04:01.029 30837-30837/edu.uconn.chatter D/ViewRootImpl: ViewPostImeInputStage processPointer 0
10-27 12:04:01.029 30837-30837/edu.uconn.chatter E/FXEntity: call native MultitouchEvent, density = 4.0, touchXs0 = 325
10-27 12:04:01.029 30837-30925/edu.uconn.chatter I/GLASS: Call

Comment: The output is too verbose, so make sure you look for the lines containing the `FXActivity` system.out. Find the id of the activity and look for your own system.out. Then edit your question with the relevant output.

Comment: See edit above. - Thx

Comment: As I said, the JavaFX ListView doesn't differ on desktop and on Android. I've just checked a sample, and it works fine for me. Can you post more details? Part of the code that defines the ListView and the listener, and what is your Android version?

Comment: See edit 2 above. - Thx

Comment: Samsung 6... we had some bad experiences with it, regarding the event handling, precisely. A working solution we've already tested is adding a mouse clicked event handler to the ListCell instead. Can you give it a try?

Comment: Before I go down a rabbit hole, is there a Gluon example you can point me to as to how to add a handler to a ListCell? - Thx

Comment: It is simple with your current code: list.setCellFactory(p -> new ListCell<String>() {
            private String item;
            {
                setOnMouseClicked(e -> System.out.println("Item: " + item));
            }
            
            @Override
            protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
                super.updateItem(item, empty); 
                this.item = item;
                ...
           }
});

Comment: If still, the cell doesn't get the event, wrap the text with a node (HBox), and install the event handler on it

Comment: Hi Jose, please see above (Edit 3). The "wrapping" approach worked. Thanks for the support. This just convinced me that I need to provide some monetary support to this effort as I'm starting to see the potential.

Comment: Glad it worked. It should have worked out of the box in the first place, but there are known issues with Samsung devices. We are already an issue on this, and we will try to fix it as soon as possible.